# Concat two variable and compare with number

Tags: javascript

Javascript Code

I am concacting two variables and comparing with a string 
Why the alert is true? Why it is not coercing??

```
 var str1 = "2";
    var str2 = "3";
    var res = str1 + str2 // return 23
    console.log(res) // 23 
    console.log("100") // 100
    alert(res > "100") // alerts true instead of false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in `res` is a string. In strings "23" is greater than "100" (looking at the first character).

Answer (score 1):

To further answer your question "why isn't javascript coercing" I'd like to quote a comment from James Thorpe

"Both sides are strings - there is nothing to coerce"

Here's a code example.

```js
console.log (23 > "100")  // false
console.log ("23" > "100")  // true
```

First console.log compares number with string - javascript coerces.

Second console.log compares string with string - nothing to coerce

Answer (score 0):

Alert is `true` because '23' is lexicographically greater than '100' ('2' > '1').

You can use `parseInt` to convert strings to numbers:

```
alert(parseInt(res) > 100);
```

Comment: You are comparing strings against strings.

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte Both sides are strings - there's nothing to coerce.

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte Nope.  Not if "coerce" means "infer what type I meant even though nothing points in that direction".  JS has rules for deciding the type of an operation, that's true - but (string) > (string) is handled as string comparison by those rules.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing strings. "100" is lower then "23" because "1"<"2".
You should parse to int if you want numerical comparison, as shown in @jh314 answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily change the string to their number representation i.e, `23` and `100` and use the comparison operator. Either prefix the values with `+` to change them to numeric value or use `parseInt()`:

```js
var str1 = "2";
var str2 = "3";
var res = str1 + str2 // return 23
console.log(res) // 23 
console.log("100") // 100
alert(+res > +"100")
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of res is `"23"` not `23`. That means it's a string and therefore when you `alert` the comparison it compares the first digit of each, `2 > 1` which is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As for “why is it not coercing?” - because both operands are strings in both cases, and because both `+` and `>` are valid operations on strings.

(Using `-` (subtract) would cause implicit coercion to number because it doesn’t make sense for strings, but concatenation and addition use the same operator. Welcome to JavaScript!)

Answer (score -1):

Your alert is comparing a string and a string.

Try: `alert(res > 100)`